# LaTeX Warning: Label `pgfidxy' multiply defined

Tags: tikz-pgf

I got the warning ``` LaTeX Warning: Label ``pgfid142' multiply defined. ``` in my log file.

**UPDATE**: Thanks for all the comments. My remark that grep couldn't find these labels anywhere but in the log file was not entirely correct, they can also be found in the aux file, e.g.

```
\pgfsyspdfmark {pgfid3}{2432904}{13289255}
\pgfsyspdfmark {pgfid3}{2432904}{13289255}
```

**SECOND UPDATE**: This is really sad: The `\dSady` does not want to get remembered. ;-) More seriously, my original suspicion was completely off, sorry for that, but my *guess* is now that there is an interference between `\tikzstyle{every picture}+=[remember picture]` and the (otherwise really cool)`tikzsymbols` package.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikzsymbols}
\tikzset{every picture/.append style={remember picture}}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{\dots}
\begin{overlayarea}{\textwidth}{7cm}
\begin{itemize}
\item[\bf\Large{\dSadey}] \dots 
\pause
\item[\bf\Large{\dSadey}] \dots 
\end{itemize}
\end{overlayarea}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Any idea how to shut this warning off?

**UPDATE**: Some "harmless" pictures do *not* cause this issue, even if one gives two nodes identical names.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{every picture/.append style={remember picture}}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{\dots}
\begin{overlayarea}{\textwidth}{7cm}
\tikz{\draw[->](0,0)--(1,0);\node(a)at (0,0){};}
\pause
\tikz{\draw[->](0,0)--(2,0);\node(a)at (0,0){};}
\end{overlayarea}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: ...I can't see why it's obvious for not attaching a MWE in this specific case; the only reason would be that your images are large - lots of code - and/or you don't want to share that.

Comment: any good editor should have a search function with which you could look for the string.  if it's in a definition, look for where that macro is called.

Comment: urk.  then it may be a composite.  is "pgfid" all by itself findable?  oh, you already said that.  sorry.

Comment: @barbarabeeton My remark was not entirely correct, these things can also be found in the aux files.

Comment: @Werner You were right, I should have provided an MWE.

Comment: You probably should have seen by now that `tikzstyle` is deprecated. Your problem comes from the fact that `beamer` reads the same slide over and over again to handle the pauses. Hence if there is a definition it will be redefined everytime beamer rereads the same slide with the visible parts. It will hence try to remember the picture in every reread

Comment: @percusse Thanks so much for the comment. (And of curse you're right about `\tikzstyle`.)Unfortunately, I don't fully understand what you mean. I cannot trigger this with ordinary pictures, please see the update.

Comment: They don't have remember picture and also I don't know the contents of `\dSadey`

Comment: @percusse I don't understand your comment and tikzsymbols, where `\dSadey` is taken from, is part of the texlive distribution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not 100% sure. But it is very likely that each symbol from `tikzsymbols` is itself a `tikzpicture`. We all know that typesetting `tikzpicture` is slow as hell. So the package probably accelerates this process by caching each symbol the first time you use it in an `hbox`. (It is the same idea behind the `.pic` handler.)

Therefore by the second time (and third, and so on) you use this symbol you are actually telling the compiler to **paste** this `hbox` to here and there. If it happens that the `hbox` contains something that should be unique, for instance a `\pdfsavepos` command, the compiler will be confused because it is told to memorize the position of two objects under the same ID.

In your case, `every picture/.append style={remember picture}` tells the compiler to memorize the positions of all following pictures. After that you call `\dSadey` the first time. So the symbol is typesetted and cached. One ID; one symbol; Nothing wrong. By the second time you call `\dSadey`, the compiler **paste** the `hbox` containing the same ID so it complains.

As you might have been noticed, the number complaint is exactly the number of `\dSadey` minus one. If you try to use `\dSadey` once before `every picture/.append style={remember picture}`, the compiler would not complain anymore because the cached `hbox` does not contain an ID.

A better way to solve this is the following

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikzsymbols}
\begin{document}

\tikzset{every picture/.append style={remember picture}}
\tikzset{/__tikzsymbols/.append style={remember picture=false}}

\begin{frame}
    \dSadey\dSadey\dSadey\dSadey\dSadey\dSadey\dSadey\dSadey\dSadey\dSadey
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

As you might guess: `/__tikzsymbols` is the style that will be applied to all symbols. By turning-off `remember picture` the `hbox` would not contain ID anymore. So the compiler would not complain anymore.

Comment: I lied a little bit. it is not the compiler complaining but [tag:PGF] does complain. In other cases such as hyperlink in `.pic` the compiler gets really mad.

Comment: Thanks a lot! There is no way I could have figured that.

Comment: The symbols definitely **are** `tikzpicture`s and they definitely **are** saved to boxes, where possible. So when you use the same symbol at the same size etc., you are re-using a box. I'm not certain of this, but I think that you can switch this off. However, that would obviously slow compilation.

Comment: I found this in th official document:
`usebox = {⟨true/false⟩}`. 
In `tikzsymbols` all symbols are stored inside boxes (`\sbox`) and while I still have no idea what exactly happens, it shortens the compilation time of the document. By default this option is true.
The drawback is that LATEX has only a limited number of box registers. If you come across an error message regarding boxes try setting `usebox=false`.