# How can I prevent or reduce multiply defined labels?

Tags: tikz-pgf, cross-referencing, boxes, warnings, backgrounds

I have a format which repeatedly uses Ti*k*Z pictures in the background of certain pages. Because these pictures require `remember picture, overlay`, they cannot be externalised. To control compilation time, I therefore save pictures I need repeatedly into boxes at the beginning of the document and then just use those boxes on the pages where I need them.

This works fine. The only problem is that I get multiply defined labels. The problem is not so much that LaTeX warns me about these, as that there are many of them and they drown out warnings I care about. In particular, I want to know if other labels get multiply defined, because that would screw up my cross-references.

So I'm trying to reduce the number of spurious warnings I get. I've made a little progress in the case of externalised images (by redefining a macro from `pageslts` only when externalising), but I need to do something different (if possible) for the pictures I'm boxing.

Here's a minimal example demonstrating the problem.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,everypage,kantlipsum}
\newsavebox\mybox

\begin{document}
\sbox\mybox{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
    \shade [top color=blue!50!black, bottom color=blue!50!black, middle color=blue!50!cyan] (current page.north west) rectangle (current page.south east);
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}%
\AddThispageHook{\usebox\mybox}
\kant[1-8]
\AddThispageHook{\usebox\mybox}
\kant[9-10]
\end{document}
```

So the point here is that the picture is generated once and saved to `\mybox`. This box is then put into the background on page 1. It is then put into the background on page 3. The output is fine.

[image: desired output]

The problem is that it generates a multiply-defined label warning

```
LaTeX Warning: Label `pgfid1' multiply defined.
```

because the `.aux` file contains

```
\pgfsyspdfmark {pgfid1}{4736286}{47362867}
\pgfsyspdfmark {pgfid1}{4736286}{47362867}
```

Is there any help for this? Obviously, the warning is spurious in the sense that it doesn't hurt anything. But my list of warnings is being swamped by spurious warnings I can't get rid of and it is getting well nigh impossible to find the ones I do need to identify, especially when I'm in a hurry.

## EDIT

Just to clarify, I know that `remember picture` is responsible for writing the labels to the `.aux` file which trigger the warnings. But removing this is not an option because `overlay` requires it:

[image: why I need <code>remember picture</code>]

Comment: Just wondering if  [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/411809/121799) is related. If you switch off the `remember option` directive, the complaints will disappear.

Comment: @marmot Yes, but I **can't** switch `remember picture` off because the whole point of doing it this way is that I need `overlay`. If I could turn `remember` off, I wouldn't save them to boxes in the first place: I'd externalise them instead. So, yes, this question is related in the sense that the issue I know is causing the warnings is the one which Symbol1 suggested was causing yours. But diagnosis contained the solution in your case - the symbols don't need to be `remember`. Unfortunately, diagnosis is not sufficient here.

Comment: @marmot See edit above for clarification. The image at the bottom shows the effect of attempting to use `overlay` without `remember picture`. This is why `overlay, remember picture` always needs 2 runs to be placed correctly: the coordinates written to the `.aux` on the first run are used to place the picture correctly on the second.

Comment: I understood that, and apologize for my not-so-clear comment above. I wanted to say that the fact that switching off the `remember picture` option cures it is further evidence that this is the same problem.

Comment: @marmot Oh, I see. Sorry. Yes. It is definitely the same cause. And I wish that I could find an equally satisfactory solution! I just meant that this question isn't a duplicate because when you say 'related' people get trigger-happy with the close button ;).

Comment: I agree that it's not a duplicate and it's my bad that I was not clear enough. I'm also looking at the `hf-tikz.sty` package, which redefines `\pgfsyspdfmark`, but you're much more experienced and will see more quickly if this makes sense. (Loading `hf-tikz.sty`  doesn't solve the problem anyway, but maybe adding some element, like an additional counter, to it could.) (+1 BTW)

Comment: Would it help to put your `\shade` in a `pic` with `\tikzset` and then reference it with `\tikz[remember picture, overlay]{\pic{`...`};}`? I don’t know how this would affect compilation time, however.

Comment: my tikz foo isn't really good enough to answer but I suspect that you do not need the remember overlay stuff. That is writing to the aux file the "current position" so that you can overlay some tikz decoration at that (typically unknown) point, but here you know where you want the tikz to go relative to the page (which is why it is writing the same coordinates every time) so you dont need the mechanism at all

Comment: If you need many of those pictures, create the boxes in the preamble (before `\begin{document}`) and use [`mylatexformat`](https://ctan.org/pkg/mylatexformat). This way you only need to compile them once if your preamble doesn't change, this could reduce compilation time a lot.

Comment: @Skillmon the OP is re-using a box so the tikz  is only being executed once anyway so the main saving of building a format would be the time to load the tikz files rather than the time to execute the tikz code

Comment: @DavidCarlisle this depends on the size of the tikz code and the number of prebuilded tikz pictures. And imho it is worth it for almost every project (and if one has a good Makefile for every project...).

Comment: @Skillmon `latexformat` is I agree a _brilliant_ idea:-) (although it was written for an age when not loading `article.sty` saved about 10 minutes.)

Comment: @Skillmon The picture can't be drawn prior to the preamble because the dimensions are affected by the document preamble. Specifically, it depends on the paper size. Also, the content of the picture depends on information set in the document preamble. So this isn't really an option unless I've misunderstood the idea.

Comment: As long as you don't specify any dimensions in `\AtBeginDocument` you can put the image in your preamble. It just has to be prior to `\begin{document}`. Up to that point you can build a format (but you could specify the end of the format prior to that).

Comment: @Skillmon I've never seen much point in building a format, so haven't. However, it wouldn't really help here. I don't want to tie myself to only specifying the Ti*k*Z code in the preamble. I want to be able to change it mid-document if I've reason to. And I certainly want to be able to change it for different documents. (I generally don't - only the colours, which aren't in the Ti*k*Z code itself and, potentially, the papersize, which affects the image's dimensions) but I could. Also, at some point, I mean to redo things so that I change the title box included in the image after page 1.

Comment: @cfr but this wouldn't be possible with boxes, too. I build a format for every real project of mine (since I've written a one-for-all makefile which does so). It saves some time but on a modern computer the gain isn't that much (still loading Ti*k*Z or my `ducksay` with ligature suppression (because of the not optimized package code) does take some time you can save yourself).

Comment: @Skillmon Not really. I can change the content of the box. So the image is compiled once for, say, the first half of the document and once for the second. That would mean each picture is compiled only once per run. And if I could drop the `remember picture, overlay`, I could externalise them, too. The Ti*k*Z code has to be loaded anyway regardless of how I handle these particular pictures. I know you're going to say I could put that in the format, but I'm not convinced the time saved is worth the inconvenience.

Answer (score 7):

As I mentioned in comments I think a real solution would be to not use the tikz remember mechanism as here you do not need to save any current coordinates as you are placing the tikz at a fixed position on the page.

However starting from here the easiest thing is just to ignore all the settings after the first by writing a command to the aux file that discards the setting.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,everypage,kantlipsum}
\newsavebox\mybox
\makeatletter
\def\eatpgfmark{\write\@auxout{\string\@gobblefour}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\sbox\mybox{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
    \shade [top color=blue!50!black, bottom color=blue!50!black, middle color=blue!50!cyan] (current page.north west) rectangle (current page.south east);
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}%
\AddThispageHook{\usebox\mybox}
\kant[1-8]
\AddThispageHook{\eatpgfmark\usebox\mybox}
\kant[9-10]
\end{document}
```

which produces an aux file

```
\relax 
\pgfsyspdfmark {pgfid1}{4736286}{47362867}
\@gobblefour
\pgfsyspdfmark {pgfid1}{4736286}{47362867}
```

so the second `\pgfsysmark` is discarded.

Comment: Thanks. What would a 'real' solution look like? (My actual picture is a bit more complicated, though, so I'm not certain a real solution would work there.)

Comment: @cfr as far as I can see you are just using the overlay mechanism to get a zero sized box that you can then put at a fixed position on the page, so you could use any tikz and make it zero sized with tikz or `\smash` or whatever and then position it on the page using a standard pagestyle, or the addthispage hook that you use above or anything else

Comment: I guess I'm being dumb. But won't that insert the picture at whatever point in the text? That is, it won't make sure that the bottom left corner of the picture is at the bottom left of the paper and the top right corner at the top right, will it?

Comment: @cfr there are many ways to add something at a specific point, that is I assume the hook you are using is doing, the classic way is to use a page style, if you use a page style with `\begin{picture}(0,0)\put(a,b){anything}\end{picture}` then `anything` will be overlaid at position a,b over the page contents

Comment: I tried `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,everypage,geometry,kantlipsum}
\newsavebox\mybox

\begin{document}
\sbox\mybox{%
  \begin{picture}(0,0)%
    \unitlength=1mm%
    \put(-25.4,25.4){%
      \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current page.north west)]
        \shade [top color=blue!50!black, bottom color=blue!50!black, middle color=blue!50!cyan] (current page.north west) rectangle (current page.south east);
      \end{tikzpicture}%
    }%
  \end{picture}%
}%
\AddThispageHook{\usebox\mybox}
\kant[1-8]
\AddThispageHook{\usebox\mybox}
\kant[9-10]
\end{document}` :(.

Comment: Oh, it is just because I forgot I'd added `geometry`, I think.

Comment: But it doesn't agree with `expl3` for some reason. (Or it doesn't agree with something - I get a horizontal offset, although the vertical alignment is fine.)

Comment: Can you add the `picture` thing so I can accept your answer? I never actually tried this method (yet) as the alternative seemed a better option.

Comment: @cfr I'm not sure what you want me to add, but feel free to edit the answer if you wish

Comment: @cfr Which alternative is a better option? You mentioned it in your comment from Feb 24 2018.—I also suffer from `current page` issues.

Comment: @RobertSiemer Er ... I don't know. But I seem to have got rid of most of my multiply defined labels. I think I'm saving a `picture` into a global hbox. I then use this in `\AddThispageHook`.  I have 3+ boxes saved once and then used repeatedly, so I'm not using `overlay`/`remember picture`.

Comment: @RobertSiemer I think 'seem**ed**' is crucial there. Past tense. That is, I think I'm using what I think David might consider closer to a 'real solution' for this.